# @Override on method onApplicationEvent

Tags: java, spring

I have a basic question...could not able to find out why its not working...below piece of code is not working when I use @Override annotation. Please help

```
public class QuartzJob
implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{ 
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working." Even if it's simple, it will help people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: I meant it was causing compile error

Comment: On the right track - just post the actual error message. For future reference, it makes your question(s) easier and faster to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that you are compiling for Java 1.5 and only from Java 1.6 implementing an interface method it is possible (and good style) to add `@Override`.

Comment: I changed Java compiler compliance level to 6.0 and it worked...strange to see interface having an abstract method though they are by default abstract and 6.0 annotation works with such kind.